# What is a ruby gem that generates simple API documentation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rest, api, ruby-on-rails-4

Is there any simple ruby gems that is able to:

1. Dynamically generate API documentation based on routes and the comments above the API Controller actions. I want the documentation in the code, for new developers, and I don't want to have to maintain separate views just for the API docs.
2. Show the API documentation website under a separate route in the app. I don't want to have to run a separate api-documentation-server just to expose the API docs.
3. Show custom comments. If I want to write a detailed explanation of the API endpoint. So, I don't want documentation that just shows the API endpoint and the request/response.
4. Specify Request and Response examples in JSON. Including specifying multiple response examples for various fail conditions.
5. (bonus) Interpret Markdown in the documentation comments.
6. (bonus) Generate and show code for requesting each API endpoint, in various languages such as: Ruby, Swift.
7. (bonus) Run real requests against the API through the API docs website.

PS: This is for a REST API, but with some custom routes, if it should make any difference in practise. I'm using Rails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am always a fan of using [Swagger](http://swagger.io/)

Comment: Does swagger necessarily require the use of a separate api documentation server?

Comment: It does not. I've only really used it for C# projects but I believe it's a relatively simply setup of adding a gem and running the install generator. Then all you would do is go to `localhost:3000/swagger`. Check [this](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/rswag) out for more details.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I found out that it could be done in Rails as well. Using https://github.com/adrian-gomez/swaggard

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are using Rails (from the tags in the questions).

I have used this [Apipie](https://github.com/Apipie/apipie-rails) to create docs for my RAILS backend service. Your first 4 points are well covered in this. They claim that they support Markup languages too. I haven't tried it.